# How can I use Screw Modifier right?

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

So I am watching a tutorial until the Screw Modifier (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebx2qbBlvh0 at 13.54 min) comes to use. I made 3 circles and added the modifier (and made sure they that don´t touch each other), but the outcome is different:[image: screw]

It should look rather like a string of wool or fabric. There´s always that cylinder im the middle that´s bothering me. I watched a special tutorial about the modifier, however it didn´t help.  How can I make it behave like in the video?

There´s my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/3logecmy0c8azhq/teddy_low2.blend?dl=0

The next step will be to apply the yarn to an edge-path with the curve-modifier, as I understand it. I may open a new question about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just select your object and go Object -> set origin > origin to geometry

[image]

Comment: You stole my DeLorean

Comment: that's right. and it dives like crazy....i LOVE it!!!